Spring Boot 3 - Constructor Injection is not working
Project Environment

Spring Boot 3.2.11
Java 21
JRE 21 -> created using jlink command (all java packages included).
Spring 6.1.14
Postgres 13
Tomcat 10.1.30

I have created a small workable Maven project in STS IDE with following project structure
Project Structure
And the code of Interface, Classes and application properties which have been used in this project are as follows below
1. ConstrInjectionApplication.java
package com.example.constrInjection;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConstrInjectionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConstrInjectionApplication.class, args);
    }
}

2.ServletInitializer.java
package com.example.constrInjection;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ConstrInjectionApplication.class);
    }

}

3.TestController.java - a rest controller class
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.constrInjection.service.DemoService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestController {

    private final DemoService demoService;

    public TestController(DemoService demoService) {
        this.demoService = demoService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getReply")
    public String sendReply() {
        return demoService.greet();
    }
}

4.DemoService - (an Interface)
package com.example.constrInjection.service;

public interface DemoService {
  public String greet();
}


DemoServiceImpl - (A class which implements the DemoService interface)

package com.example.constrInjection.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.constrInjection.dao.DemoRepo;

@Service(value = "demoService")
public class DemoServiceImpl implements DemoService {

    private final DemoRepo demoRepo;

    public DemoServiceImpl(DemoRepo demoRepo) {
        this.demoRepo = demoRepo;
    }

    public String greet() {
        return demoRepo.getDemoRepoStatus();
    }
}

6.DemoRepo.java - (an Interface)
package com.example.constrInjection.dao;

public interface DemoRepo {

    public String getDemoRepoStatus();
}

7.DemoRepoImpl.java - (a class which implements DemoRepo)
package com.example.constrInjection.dao;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.constrInjection.pojo.Test1;

@Repository(value = "demoRepo")
public class DemoRepoImpl implements DemoRepo {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    /**
     * @param jdbcTemplate
     */
    public DemoRepoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
    @Override
    public String getDemoRepoStatus() {
        String sql = "select * from test1 where id=1";
        Test1 t1 = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Test1.class);
        return t1==null?"No Message":t1.getMessage();
    }

}


8. application.properties
spring.application.name=constrInjection
#Sever Configuration
server.port=8080
#Context Path
server.servlet.context-path=/constrInjection
#Application Configuration
spring.main.web-application-type=servlet
#Database Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5436/mytest
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin@123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format.sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

9.pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.11</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>constrInjection</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>constrInjection</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url />
    <licenses>
        <license />
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer />
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection />
        <developerConnection />
        <tag />
        <url />
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

10. Test1.java - (a pojo class)
package com.example.constrInjection.pojo;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "test1")
public class Test1 {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String message;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}

11. a sample table script
-- Table: public.test1

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.test1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test1
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    message character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.test1
    OWNER to postgres;

When I ran this project on STS IDE with Tomcat 10.1 embedded server. It works fine. But When I create a war file using Maven Build command and deployed on the Tomcat 10.1.30 Server it does not works.
Log File
The tomcat log which I have observed on my machine as follows below
Google drive link for log file
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NX27tRHW5fimFlKhp841Jbbpd2qKtMWLTGbVxs8-ScA/edit?usp=sharing
To come over the issue I have tried several ways on tomcat 10.1.30 by modifying the
Java options
Tomcat 10.1.30 Java configurations

Like setting the JVM options on catalina.bat file

 set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% --add-modules jdk.unsupported"
 set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% --add-opens java.base/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED"


Adding the -Dspring.objenesis.ignore=true settings

Added the plug in in pom.xml


    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>--add-modules jdk.unsupported</jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

It did not work at all. After so many tries, I'm posting this issue on SOF and I appreciate if anybody have some idea to resolve this issue.
Thanking you all......

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
